# SonarQube report link on jenkins not working

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube report link on jenkins not working, it is a text rather than a hyperlink.

Another question is if i do the build only and do not run sonar analysis, still i will get the report ( could be the earlier one runned ) on my jenkins page? 
I am asking this as few of my jobs are giving hyperlink for Sonar report and others are not.

What could be the possible resolution?

I have tried setting sonar.analysis.mode=publish , but this didn't work.

Comment: What version of the Jenkins plugin are you using?

Comment: SonarQube Scanner 2.8

Comment: The current version of the [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) is 2.6.1

Comment: SonarQube Runner we are using SonarQubeScanner_2.8. Irrespective of version, could you please tell me what could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: I have one more query, if i do build only in my jenkins build, still the sonar analysis link work or not?

Comment: Please help if anyone have any solution?